# Including labels in a macro for a questionnaire

Tags: macros, labels

I'm writing a questionnaire in LaTeX, and want to make a macro for questions. One feature I want is to cross-reference questions using labels (e.g. in case you want to skip a question. Here's a MWE of what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,textcomp,amsmath,longtable}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\stepcounter{qnumber}

\newcommand{\question}[3]{
\hfill \theqnumber\hfill\hfill & #1 & #2 & #3\stepcounter{qnumber}\\ \hline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|c|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Sl.} & 
\textbf{Question text} & 
\textbf{Instructions for enumerator (not to be read out)} &
\textbf{Response options} 
\\ \hline

\question{What is your age?}{Enter age in years}{18--99}    
\question{Do you rent your house?}{}{1. Yes; 2. No}    

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

What I would like is to have another set of curly braced in `\question` where a label can be given to the question, which then allows for cross referencing of question numbers. For example:

```
\question{Do you rent your house}{lab:rent}
\question{If you answered "Yes" in question \ref{lab:rent}, how much do you pay per month}
```

How can I adapt the `\newcommand` line to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, for example, use an optional argument to `\question` which becomes the label if not empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,textcomp,amsmath,longtable}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}

\newcommand{\question}[4][]{%
  \refstepcounter{qnumber}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \label{#1}%
  \fi
  \hfill\theqnumber\hfill\hfill & #2 & #3 & #4\\ \hline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|c|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Sl.} & 
\textbf{Question text} & 
\textbf{Instructions for enumerator (not to be read out)} &
\textbf{Response options}
\\ \hline

\question{What is your age?}{Enter age in years}{18--99}
\question[lab:rent]{Do you rent your house?}{}{1. Yes; 2. No}
\question{If you answered "Yes" in question \ref{lab:rent}, how much do you pay per month}{}{}

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

> [image]